# Different categories of memory

Tags: c++, memory, stack

```
static const int MAX_SIZE = 256; //I assume this is static Data

bool initialiseArray(int* arrayParam, int sizeParam) //where does this lie?
{ 
 if(size > MAX_SIZE) 
 { 
 return false; 
 } 

 for(int i=0; i<sizeParam; i++) 
 { 
 arrayParam[i] = 9; 
 } 

 return true; 
} 

void main() 
{ 
 int* myArray = new int[30]; //I assume this is allocated on heap memory
 bool res = initialiseArray(myArray, 30); //Where does this lie?
 delete myArray; 
}
```

We're currently learning the different categories of memory, i know that theres
-Code Memory
-Static Data
-Run-Time Stack
-Free Store(Heap)

I have commented where im unsure about, just wondering if anyone could help me out. My definition for the Run-Time stack describes that this is used for functions but my code memory defines that it contains all instructions for the methods/functions so im just a bit confused.

Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static const int MAX_SIZE = 256; //I assume this is static Data
```

Yes indeed. In fact, because it's `const`, this value might not be kept in your final executable at all, because the compiler can just substitute "256" anywhere it sees `MAX_SIZE`.

```
bool initialiseArray(int* arrayParam, int sizeParam) //where does this lie?
```

The code for the `initialiseArray()` function will be in the data section of your exectuable. You can get a pointer to the memory address, and call the function via that address, but other than that there's not much else you can do with it.

The `arrayParam` and `sizeParam` arguments will be passed to the function by value, on the stack. Likewise, the `bool` return value will be placed into the calling function's stack area.

```
int* myArray = new int[30]; //I assume this is allocated on heap memory
```

Correct.

```
 bool res = initialiseArray(myArray, 30); //Where does this lie?
```

Effectively, the `myArray` pointer and the literal `30` are copied into the stack area of `initialiseArray()`, which then operates on them, and then the resulting `bool` is copied into the stack area of the calling function.

The actual details of argument passing are a lot more grizzly and depend on calling conventions (of which there are several, particularly on Windows), but unless you're doing something really specialised then they're not really important :-)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response Tristan, makes things a bit clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

The stack is used for *automatic* variables - that is, variables declared within functions, or as function parameters. These variables are destroyed automatically when the program leaves the block of code they were declared in.

You're correct that `MAX_SIZE` has a *static* lifetime - it is destroyed automatically at the end of the program. You're also correct that the array allocated with `new[]` is on the heap (having a *dynamic* lifetime) - it won't be destroyed automatically, so need to be deleted. By the way, you need `delete [] myArray;` to match the use of `new []`.

The pointer to it (`myArray`) is an automatic variable, on the stack, as are `res` and the function arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike, yourself and Tristan have helped me out a great amount

Answer (score 0):

There is just one type of memory... it is a memory :D
What is different is where it is and how you access it.

If you go deep into the exe loader in Windows ( or in any kind of OS actually ) what it really does is that is stores the information of your sections ( parts of you exe ) and at run time at lays it out properly into the memory and applies access rights. So generally the code section where your "program" is the same memory ( your RAM ) as your data section. The difference is that the access rights are different, the code section usually only have read + execute the data just read + write ( and no execute ).

The stack is still a memory, it is special in the sense that it is again controlled by the OS, the stack size is the size in bytes of how big your stack is, but here the purpose is to hold immediate values between function calls ( as per stdcall ) and local variables ( depends on the compiler how it does it exactly ) so because it is a memory you CAN use it but like you it is to to lets say allocate a 10000 byte string on the stack. In assembly you have direct access since there is a stack pointer EBP ( If I remember correctly :P ) or in C/C++ you can use alloca.

The new and the delete operators are built ins for the C++ language but as far as I know they use the same system allocators as you do, in fact you can override them and use malloc/free and it should work which means that again this is the same memory.

The difference between using new/delete and an os specific function is that you let the language handle the allocation but in the end you will get a pointer just like you would with any other function.

On top of this there are special ways but those change the way the memory handled, in Windows this is the virtual memory for example, like VirutalAlloc, VirutalFree will allow you specify what you will do with the memory you want to use thus you allow the OS to optimize better, like you tell it I want 2Gb of memory BUT it doesn't have to be in RAM, so it may save it on the disk but you STILL access this with memory pointers.

And about your questions :

```
static const int MAX_SIZE = 256; //I assume this is static Data
```

It usually depends on the compiler but mostly they will treat this as const ( static is something else ) which means that it will be in the const section of the exe which in turn means that this memory block will be read-only.

```
 int* myArray = new int[30]; //I assume this is allocated on heap memory
```

Yes this will be on the heap, but how it is allocated depends on the implementation and whenever you override the new operator, if you do you can for example force it to be in the Virtual memory so in fact it could be on the disk or in RAM, but this is silly thing to do so yes it will be on the heap.

```
bool res = initialiseArray(myArray, 30); //Where does this lie?
```

Multiple things happen here, because the compiler know that the first parameter of initialiseArray must be a pointer to an int it will pass a pointer to myArray so both a pointer and the value of 30 will go on the stack and then the function is called.
In the function which is in the memory ( the code section ) it runs and gets the parameters ( int* arrayParam, int sizeParam ) from the stack it will know that you want to write to the arrayParam and that is is pointer so it will write into the location arrayParam points to. To where exactly you specify it with arrayParam[i] < i will offset the memory pointer to the correct value, again C++ does some magic by adjusting the pointer for you since the adjustment in code should be in bytes it will move the memory pointer by 4 since ( usually ) int == 4 bytes.

To get a better overview of where goes what and how it works, use a debugger or a disassembler ( like OllyDbg ) and see it for yourself, if you want know more about how the stack is used look up the stdcall calling convention.

Comment: You cannot use new, malloc and o/s calls interchangeably.

Comment: An explanation would be nice :) Oh you probably mean that I cannot interchange like malloc and HeapFree with the OS for example, yes I forgot to mention that since I was assuming it is rather obvious :D